# Correct way to nest arrays of elements inside HTML forms

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, forms

I have an HTML Form that contains groups of similar items. I know HTML has no concept of "arrays" so I'm wondering what is the best way to write something that contains a single form and can have multiple groups of the same items added as needed.

```
<form>

    <div>
        <input name="title[]">
        <textarea name="body[]">
    </div>

    <div>
        <input name="title[]">
        <textarea name="body[]">
    </div>

    <a href="#" id="addrow">Add row</a>

    <input type="submit">

</form>
```

Comment: And what seems wrong with this notation to you? It's actually quite popular.

Comment: you can provide an index for each array, to the page, its just a string for a name, but your backend can parse it as an array. For example: title[0], title[1]

Comment: HTML doesn't know arrays, but plenty of server side languages, like PHP do.

Comment: Those `<div>`s should probably be `<fieldset>`s.

Comment: Generally the only elements in an html form that share the same name are groups of checkboxes and groups of radio buttons. Of these, radio buttons are mutually exclusive, so only one is sent to the server. Checkboxes and Options (in a multiple select) are the only elements whose values are sent as an array. Give your other elements (text selects and textareas) unique names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have something like this:

```
<form method="post">

<input type="hidden" name="num_of_elements" value="2">

<div>
    <input name="title[0]">
    <textarea name="body[0]">
</div>

<div>
    <input name="title[1]">
    <textarea name="body[1]">
</div>

<a href="#" id="addrow">Add row</a>

<input type="submit">
```

When you add div with javascript/php or whatever, just add count of elements in hidden input num_of_elements

and then when you submit it in PHP you would have variables like:

```
$count = intval($_POST['num_of_elements']);
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
{
echo $_POST["title[{$i}]"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work:

```
<form>

    <div>
        <input name="title[0]">
        <textarea name="body[0]">
    </div>

    <div>
        <input name="title[1]">
        <textarea name="body[1]">
    </div>

    <a href="#" id="addrow">Add row</a>

    <input type="submit">

</form>
```